# How can I get bracket pair colorization inside strings in VS Code?

Tags: twig, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I'm using the [Twig Language 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2) extension to deal with Twig-like syntax inside HTML files (actually I use the [Pebble](https://pebbletemplates.io/) templating engine). I configured VS Code so the brackets are colorized:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.html": "twig"
},
"[twig]": {
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true
},
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#15d31e",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#15d31e",
  "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000"
}
```

The colorization (green, in my case) works well when the `{{` and `}}` brackets are used "at the elements level" of the HTML file, but not when they are *inside a string*. For example:

[image: example]

Since the Twig/Pebble blocks are interpreted even when they are inside a string, it would make sense, in my opinion, to highlight the brackets there too.

Is this possible?

Comment: I noticed the same with the [Jinja2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml) templating language, so I assume that this might be a limitation of the VS Code parsing. However, I am curious for a possible solution as well.

Comment: Might be worth opening an issue on the [extension's GitHub page](https://github.com/mblode/vscode-twig-language-2).

Comment: did you figure out how to do this? I have followed some other comments and most point to deprecated extensions which have a message "this functionality is now built into vscode" I've tried enabling the vscode feature but still can't get color highlights for brackets.

Comment: @algorythms Nope

Comment: It seems likely this is related to the fact it won't highlight brackets at all within a string in any language (that I've tried), or a "text file". Even with all the "highlight matching brackets" settings are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be tracked by an open issue ticket in the VS Code GitHub repo (which would mean that it's currently not supported): [Enable bracket colorization within Strings #146453](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146453). Give it a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

Answer (score 1):

The extension 2gua.rainbow-brackets does apply Bracket colorization within Strings... but it doesn't seem like you can edit the choice of bracket colors, and they don't contrast well with the color of string text

Comment: It's always a good practice to link the page of the stuff you're suggesting / mentioning, in this case the VS Code extension.

Comment: Oh, right. I will pay attention to this in the future. Thanks for the advice.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets