# editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs is not working in template literals in JavaScript and TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

**settings.json**

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs": [
    ["[", "]"],
    ["(", ")"],
    ["{", "}"],
    ["<", "</"],
    ["<", "/>"]
],
```

How can I enable bracket pairs in template literals in JavaScript and TypeScript files?

from this

[image]

like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is *almost* a duplicate of [How can I get bracket pair colorization inside strings in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71093558/11107541). Except that VS Code *does* support bracket pair colourization in template string literals for JavaScript and TypeScript files- except that it only supports it for `${...}` placeholders and for bracket pairs inside the `${...}` placeholders. If you want support for `editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs` inside JS/TS template strings but outside of placeholders, then you'll probably need to wait on [Enable bracket colorization within Strings #146453](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146453).